# Invalid or unexpected token in Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

Even though I searched all over stackoverflow for the fix, I can't get past this error in Cypress:

"The following error comes from your application code, not from Cypress.

Invalid or unexpected token

When Cypress detects uncaught errors coming from your application, it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable and you can choose to disable this by listening for the uncaught:exception event."

I've tried including the "main" workaround, whereby I put in the support/index.js code

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false
})
```

The problem occurs in the console when cypress has to click on a selector for a menu on the page, which leads to a certain page.

This happens on a Public Release environment. On the base, staging environment, it works. Specifically, in cy.intercept() required and in cy.visit() instead of "/Public/" I changed to "/PublicRelease/".  I've changed the links, intercepts and everything, but maybe I'm missing something.